CSS for bootstrap accordion
So I'm pretty new to css and bootstrap, and have added an accordian into my view page. I have tried to alter the original css but with no luck!
<div class="accordion accordian-flush" id="accordionExample">
@foreach (var s in Model.Data)
{
        <div class="accordion-item">

            <h2 class="accordion-header">

                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse@(s.Id)"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse@(s.Id)">
                    @s.Name
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapse@(s.Id)" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                   <p><strong>Email: </strong>@s.Email</p>
                <p><strong>Manager: </strong>A name</p>

                <p><a asp-condition=@User.IsInRole("admin") class="btn-add p-0 m-0" asp-action="Details"
                asp-route-id="@s.Id"
                aria-label="see shop details">Details</a></p> 
                </div>
            </div>
                
        </div>

}
</div>

This is my view page and I will show you what I have tried adding in my style sheet...
.accordion{
  --bs-accordion-btn-bg:#1D976C;
  --bs-accordion-active-bg: red;
}

Finally these are the links in my _layout
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/EmployeeEntry.Web.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.2/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

I have tired watching youtube tutorials but they show similar things and I'm just not sure what to do next! Any help would be appreciated

I updated the answer to add another solution, you can check it and verify whether they are working or not.

The issue might related the bootstrap CSS version.
Try to open the /lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css file and check the Bootstrap version, you might using Bootstrap v5.1.0 version, like this:

When use the above version, the --bs-accordion-active-bg will not working.
To solve this issue,
Solution 1:
you can try to use the bootstrap@5.3.3 version, instead of v5.1.0 version.
You can modify your code as below: replace the bootstrap.min.css file to the latest bootstrap CDN reference.
@*     <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" /> *@
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

and add the collapsed class for the accordion button.
<div class="accordion accordian-flush" id="accordionExample">
    @foreach (var s in Model.Data)
    {
        <div class="accordion-item"> 
            <h2 class="accordion-header">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse@(s.Id)"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse@(s.Id)">
                    @s.Name
                </button>
            </h2> 
            <div id="collapse@(s.Id)" class="accordion-collapse collapse " data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    <p><strong>Email: </strong>@s.Email</p>
                    <p><strong>Manager: </strong>A name</p>

                    <p>
                        <a asp-condition=@User.IsInRole("admin") class="btn-add p-0 m-0" asp-action="Details"
                           asp-route-id="@s.Id"
                           aria-label="see shop details">Details</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div> 
    }
</div> 

Then the result as below:

Update:
Solution 2
If you still want to use the Bootstrap v5.1.0 version (using <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />), you can add the following CSS style:
<style> 
    .accordion-button {
        background-color: #1D976C;
    }
    .accordion-button:not(.collapsed){
        background-color:red;
    } 
</style>

Then add the collapsed class for the accordion button.
You can also get the same result:


I ended up using the second solution! Thank you for your help!
